# Android Thread join stuck

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I run Thread join in my application :

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Stop Recorder Thread");
            //Do my stuff
        }
    });
    thread.start();

    if (!async) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But in some devices when the `thread.join();` called the application get stuck(but the thread didn't start), any idea what can cause this?

Comment: did  you call the join on the UI THread?

Comment: Yep, But the stuck happen only in some devices

Comment: It blocks until the thread exits. If the thread doesn't exit, it blocks forever. I've never used `Thread.join()` in production code in 17.5 years. Why do you think it's necessary?

Comment: @EJP, what about if the thread exits before `join()` is executed?

Comment: @tambykojak The Thread not start and the app is stuck

Comment: Use handler if you want to notify or send back something from another thread.